# Preparing CSV files for pm4py event-log conversion

Tags: data-mining

I've been starting a new project related to process discovery. Therefore, I want to use pm4py to work with variants etc.

I found the following code in the documentation:

```
def import_csv(filename):
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')
    dataframe = pm4py.format_dataframe(dataframe, case_id='case:concept:name', activity_key='concept:name', timestamp_key='time:timestamp')
    event_log = pm4py.convert_to_event_log(dataframe)
    return event_log
```

and get this error:

> Exception: case:concept:name column (case ID) is not in the dataframe!

My csv-file has the following columns:

```
case_id;activity;timestamp;costs;resource
```

I know that I need to declare the other columns somehow but I have no idea about the syntax. Can anyone help?

Thanks and kind regards
Aaron